# Small world in a room with a ghost

Tags: story-identification, tv, episode-identification, the-twilight-zone

I remember an episode, I think it was from *The Twilight Zone* or *The Outer Limits*.

A scientist finds a rock.

There is a world simulation happening on that rock, wherein grows a small simulation of our own evolution (by chance?)

The rock is then put in a room, inside a glass.

The scientist monitoring the rock world's evolution follows it with great interest as a comparative history method of our own evolution, and in hopes of predicting our own future, as they are evolving very quickly in a way very similar to the Earth´s history.

By the time it reaches the equivalent of our time and they master atomic energy, there appears a shadow around the rock.

The shadow turns out to be a ghost that does not let the observer follow the experiment or even get near the rock anymore.

Any idea of what episode is this?

Comment: While not the answer, for a moment this reminded me of The Science of Discworld, where the wizards accidentally create Earth in a glass sphere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually did even not remember that was also a similar series to *The Twilight Zone* called *The Outer Limits* before starting searching for the answer. It would not be the first time searching, but this time I just browsed the description of all episodes of the series of *The Twilight Zone*, and there found a reference to *The Outer Limits*.

Actually, I was thinking of Episode 8 from Season 2 of *The Outer Limits*, "Wolf 359", from 1964.

From [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667852/?ref_=ttep_ep8):

> A scientist creates a tiny model of another solar system's planet,
>   seeding it with life, to study planetary development. The
>   miniaturization allows the simulation's evolution to advance much
>   faster. A ghostly bat-like creature hovers on the in-closed model
>   watching the humans, while emitting waves of fear terrifying them.

Confirming the plot from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_359_(The_Outer_Limits)):

> As the evolution of the miniature world progresses, Meredith observes
>   a reproduction of the darkest moments of Earth's history at its
>   surface (including the development of nuclear weapons). Lowering his
>   guard one night, the scientist is suddenly attacked by the creature;
>   he is however saved by his wife, who returned from home at the same
>   moment, and who breaks the miniature planet's containment cell,
>   causing its atmosphere to escape, and subsequently causing the
>   creature to be destroyed along with the planet.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks, will do it. Thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are conflating this episode "The Little People"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:The_Little_People_(The_Twilight_Zone)
with Theodore Sturgeon's "Microcosmic God". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcosmic_God  You wouldn't be the first.

Comment: I think it was none of both. The scientist was just an observer, and did not interact with the small world.

Comment: I withdraw my answer.  I have, of course, seen the Outer Limits but not as frequently as the TZ episodes.  Maybe caught the one in question just once.

Comment: Nonetheless, your links are interesting. Thanks.

Comment: George R.R. Martin's story "Sandkings" shares some thematic similarities as well.  Ironically, it was made into a two parter for the "New Outer Limits".